# Get Data from HTML Table with Jquery (Or other ways if possible)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a really big HTML Table with data formatted like this (a simplified version of my table):

https://pastebin.com/K5UB4cGB

The list is much bigger.

I need to know which Application runs on which Server(multiple).

I now need to somehow get all the data and store it (maybe in an array) so I can work with it.
(For example I need to compare certain applications and write a code to document it.)

I've already tried many methods I found on the web but I not sure im working in the right way.

My recent atempt is:

```js
var data = Array();

$("table").each(function(i, v) {
  data[i] = Array();
  $(this).each(function(ii, vv) {
    data[i][ii] = $(this).text();
  });
})

document.write(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <th>1</th>
    <th>2</th>
    <th>3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
  </tr>
</table>


<div id="result" style="color: #f00"></div>
```

Outputs:

```
1 2 3 4 6 7 8 9 10
```

With this method I get one array:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
```

But I cannot access the stored vaules because for example data[0] outputs all the values and not only one.

Sorry for the long text

Thanks for your help :)

Kind Regards,
Markus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to iterate rows and within rows iterate cells

You can do this all with `map()`

```js
var data = $('tr').map(function() {
  return [$(this).children().map(function() {
    return $(this).text().trim()
  }).get()];
}).get();



console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>
</table>


<div id="result" style="color: #f00"></div>
```

Comment: Is there a way I can sort the values by its row? So for example 3 arrays for 123, 456, 789 ? I need to get all columnwise. So for example (1,4,7)  (2,5,8) (3,6,9). Is there a way I can do that?

Comment: What i the output of the script? I dont see any output only the table?

Comment: Hit F12 and look in developer tools console. That's what `console.log()` does...outputs there

Answer (score 1):

You can try using nested for loops and get a nested array of data.

```js
let data = [];

$("table tr").each(function() {
  let row = [];
  $(this).children("td").each(function() {
    row.push($(this).text());
  })
  data.push(row);
})

console.log(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `each` to loop through `td` and get its text value

```js
var val=[]
$('#table td').each(function(e){
val.push($(this).text())
})
console.log(val)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table">
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>10</td>
      </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @House97_ can you please verify it if it is the result that you expected,thanks

Comment: Yes it worked but my problem is: The file I need to get the data from has the a table header (th) but I also need to add that to the array.... Sorry I wrote a comment but it was deleted somehow. Is there a way I can sort the values by its column? I need to get all columnwise. So for example (1,4,7) (2,5,8) (3,6,9). Is there a way I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

In the following I am using an each function to derive the data of the table and then pushing into an array list. I hope this code is helpful. This code is really small.

```js
var arr = [];
$("th, td").each(function(){
  arr.push($(this).text());
  $("#result").text(arr);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>
</table>


<div id="result" style="color: #f00"></div>
```